# Check if a value hasn't changed more than 10^-3?

Tags: java

So i have two iterations with a few values, x being the most important one. I have to use doubles, no integers.

I need to check if the x value from the second iteration hasn't changed more than 10^-3 then from the x value in the first iteration. Here's a quick minimized preview of the code and an if statement where i tried to do the comparison. Unfortunately, the comparison isn't working as expected.

```
(while z < 10) {
  x = do some math stuff
  z++;
}

firstX = x; // store the x value from the first iteration
z = 0;

(while z < 100) {
  x = again some math stuff.

}


if((firstX - x) < Math.pow(10, -3)){
  System.out.println("value hasn't changed more than 10^-3");
} else {
  System.out.println("value has changed more than 10^-3");
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Code formatting

Comment: You should compare the absolute value of firstX - X if you are interested in the change.

Comment: This logic doesn't check for both increase and decrease. Only one of the two. Try `Math.abs(firstX - x)` in the if condition if you are using `int`.

Comment: move 10^3 to a static var, and use Math.abs(firstX - x) < epsilon. This way you will also consider negative values

Comment: @M.Soyturk, would you like to show what you mean?

Comment: @Prometheus Omar already explained my point.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, if you are looking for a change you probably mean either an increase or decrease.

```
if((firstX - x) < Math.pow(10, -3))
```

This line only checks for one of the two. If you are using integers try replacing it with the following from [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class. This is part of `java.lang.Math` which shouldn't require an import.

```
if(Math.abs(firstX - x) < Math.pow(10, -3))
```

You might also want to consider putting `Math.pow(10, -3)` in a constant if it is repeatedly referenced in code or the check is frequently invoked to increase readability (and performance if it's a hot spot).

Comment: Math,pow(10, -3) may be replaced with a constant: `public static final double EPS = 1E-3;`  Aside comment: classes from `java.lang` package do not have to be imported, other examples of the classes in this package are Object, String, Integer, etc. :)

Comment: Constant is what I meant, thanks. You are correct regarding `java.lang` imports. As you can see I haven't coded Java in a while :p.

Answer (score 0):

@m-soyturk has mentioned in the comments what I consider is the best way. Taking `10E-3` as an *epsilon* value, the following should fit.

```
if(Math.abs(firstX - x) < 0.001){ //Math.pow() - since the epsilon is constant I am against using it. Use 0.001 or 1E-3 instead
  System.out.println("value hasn't changed more than 10^-3");
} else {
  System.out.println("value has changed more than 10^-3");
}
```

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean. Yea to be honest what's the point of using Pow if it's something you can easily type out yourself.

Comment: For this case it is of no use, why compute while you know the exact value(since it is constant)?